# Lua with Apache on Linux (Ubuntu Server) errors?

Tags: linux, apache, module, lua, httpd.conf

Iv'e been trying to set up a web server off my homes internet. At the moment its a dusty little Toshiba Netbook with and Ubuntu server running off of it. I have all that set up, and apache + php, but now i'm trying to get lua to work with it. I first edited the htttpd.conf to have the

`LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so`

line uncommented so it would load (I somehow got it to install with all the modules enabled, just not active), and I got this error after trying to start it back up.

`httpd: Syntax error on line 116 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_lua.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_lua.so: undefined symbol: luaL_loadbufferx`

Since this isn't working and I have no idea why, I'd like to ask you all for help! Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `mod_lua.so` is unable to find the Lua library (in which `luaL_loadbufferx` function is implemented). Verify that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` includes path to Lua library folder, and that the user account under which the web server runs has execute privileges on `liblua51.so`.

Comment: Sorry for my noobyness, but what is the "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" and how to I set it? I coudn't find it after a bit of googling. I tried to edit a couple files, apache or otherwise, and accoriding to the <code>env</code> command there is no <code>LD_LIBRARY_PATH</code> variable. I'd really appreciate it if you'd help my noobyness :)  (Also, where do I find the <code>liblua51.so</code> file? And can I only use Lua 5.1 with it, I have Lua 5.2.3 installed)